# Make Edge Loop Mirror Another Edge Loop

Tags: edges

I made two edge loops and managed to flip one of them around using E then F, but the other one won't flip around.

I want the top edge loop to mirror the bottom one (both in orange)

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Because your geometry is not symmetrical I think you will have to do it manually by selecting the edge and press CTRL + "E" > Edge Slide (After placing the Edge Loop).

Comment: @Dontwalk I just tried that but it's the same result. I can get the top one to flip the way I want, but then the bottom one follows the top one's symmetry and vice versa. I just can't get them to mirror each other.